# angularjs - how to access variable attribute name by another variable

Tags: angularjs

I was looking for hours, and couldn't find a solution for this.

I have the following:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.varName = "x";
    $scope.x = "Hello World!";
}
```

Now, I need to access x, but its name is in another variable, something like:

```
<td>{{ {{ varName }} }}</td>
```

Which doesn't work. Some other variations also didn't work.

Any idea if that is even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use a map in the controller to store such objects as,

```
$scope.dynaMap.x = "Hello world"
```

In the html code, do

```
<td>{{ dynaMap[varName] }}</td>
```

Here, i assume `varName` is `x`

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.varName = "x";
    $scope.x = "Hello World!";
    $scope.getValueFromScopeProperty = function(propName) {
        return $scope[propName];
    };
}
```

and then:

```
<td>{{getValueFromScopeProperty(varName)}}</td>
```